# Spacy token.lemma_ not identifying nouns and pronouns

Tags: spacy, pos-tagger, lemmatization

I have been following a tutorial on Lemmatization -> https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/lemmatization-examples-python/

As told in the spacy lemmatization section, I loaded the `'en-core-web-sm'` model, parsed and extracted the lemmas of each word from a given sentence.

My code is as below

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable=['parser', 'ner'])

sentence = "The striped bats are hanging on their feet for best"

doc = nlp(sentence)

lemmatized_spacy_output = " ".join([token.lemma_ for token in doc])
print(lemmatized_spacy_output)
```

For input

```
"The striped bats are hanging on their feet for best"
```

It gives the output as

```
the stripe bat be hang on their foot for good
```

while the expected output is

```
the strip bat be hang on -PRON- foot for good'
```

As can be seen, the `stripes` word should be identified as a verb, but for some reason it is being classified as a noun (as the output is stripe, not strip).
Also, it is not identifying personal pronouns, and is giving the tokens as it is.

I have already tried a lot of github and stackoverflow questions, but none target my query.

Comment: The tutorial looks like it's for spaCy v2.x instead of v3.x, where some of this behavior has changed.

Comment: @aab my spacy version shows 3.0.3. Could you please elaborate on what behavior has been changed in spacy 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

Just like aab said in his comment. Which version are you using? I use version 3 of spacy and calling

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable=['parser', 'ner'])
sentence = "The striped bats are hanging on their feet for best"
doc = nlp(sentence)

for token in doc:
    print(token.text, " -- ", token.pos_, " -- ",token.lemma_)
```

returns

```
The  --  DET  --  the
striped  --  VERB  --  stripe
bats  --  NOUN  --  bat
are  --  VERB  --  be
hanging  --  VERB  --  hang
on  --  ADP  --  on
their  --  PRON  --  their
feet  --  NOUN  --  foot
for  --  ADP  --  for
best  --  ADJ  --  good
```

This means `striped` is identified as a verb

Comment: my spacy version is 3.0.3. As long as I recall, verb version of striped should be strip, and noun version should be stripe (Refer to the article I've linked in the question). Also, even though token.pos shows PRON, but their is still show as their, and not as -PRON-. What to do to get the output as PRON?

Comment: If you want to get exactly the same outputs as in the article, you need to downgrade your spacy to v2. I am not sure anymore, what is your concern. Do you think you're doing something wrong, because you get different results? This is perfectly fine, don't worry and continue learning from your article

Comment: I'll definitely try downgrading to v2. My concern was just to get the result that has been shown in the article. I thought probably some other functionalities would provide me the exact output as in the article. Anyway, thanks for the help!